# Can't make a get request with header to an api

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to make a get request to an api,but there is en error: Failed to fetch, what might be wrong here?

```js
const getData = () => {
  fetch("https://test-docs.stores.kg/api/categories", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      secretKey: "test_key",
      accept: "application/json "
    }
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => console.log(res));
};

getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the API you're querying is not setting a CORS header (check for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Therefore your request is being blocked.
[image: cors_issue]

If you are in control of this API adjust the webserver settings to set the appropriate header: e.g.

- "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://YOUR_WEB_FRONTEND_DOMAIN.TLD"
- (or if you just want to get it to work in a development setup)
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

You can also test the API in this Tool here
https://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=%20https%3A%2F%2Ftest-docs.stores.kg%2Fapi%2Fcategories&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote